# nginx - Can I configure a global error document?

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx configuration with a whole bunch of `server {}` blocks. I want to share error pages between them all, but many of them have different document roots. I can use a configuration like

```
error_page   404              /404.html;
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
```

outside of the server blocks and it gets shared, but then I have to put those same documents in all the roots, or have rules like

```
location = /404.html {
    root /srv/http/errors;
}
location = /50x.html {
    root /srv/http/errors;
}
```

in all my server blocks.

Is there a way to share these documents without repeating myself over and over or having many copies in the filesystem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the magic of an include directive to specify all the necessary boilerplate, then just `include /etc/nginx/standard-error-pages.conf` in each vhost (make it part of the standard vhost template in your config management system).  This also makes it real easy to override the error pages for a specific vhost (by not putting the include into that vhost config).